# Show image file

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm writing a matlab method which get 2 parameters: uint8 image and grey level which all pixels with gray level larger than par_1 are set to white.

How can I show a image after my all actions ?

Here's my code:

```
function im = function_1(img, par_1)
checkUint8Image = isa(img, 'uint8');
if checkUint8Image
    im = uint8(img);
    [row, column] = size(im);
    im2 = ones(row, column); % white image
    for i=1:row
        for j=1:column
            if(im(i,j) <= par_1)
                im2(i,j) = im(i,j);
            end
        end
    end
    imshow(im2);
else
    disp('im paramter is not a uint8 type');
end
```

Maybe there is another way to solve this problem.

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Maybe your image is out of range. Scale it unit8 from 0 to 255 or double from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either use a value for `par_1` where the whole image get sets to 1, that's why you get a white image, or you're having a scaling issue, that can be solved with the `[]` argument to `imshow`.

Shorter version of your function:

```
function im = function_1(img, par_1)
validateattributes(img, {'uint8'}, {'2d'});
    im=img;
    im(im > par_1)=1;
    imshow(im, [], 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
end
```

Let's test it with your image and a value of `100` (the original image has values between 0 and 255, setting pixels to 1 will make them look black). Let's try it:

```
Testim=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJsPY.png');
function_1(Testim, 100);
```

Result:

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: @Cieja as per [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) `imwrite` saves images of the type uint8 automatically as 8-bit values.

Comment: I have a question about your code. Now a pixels is change to balck not white. I've tried change im(im > par_1)=1; to im(im > par_1)=0;, but it's not help;

Comment: @Cieja like I said, in an image where pixels are in the range 0-255 a value of 1 is equivalent to black. If you want white assign 255. Or scale the whole image between 0 and 1 first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
  function im = function_1(img, par_1)
  checkUint8Image = isa(img, 'uint8');
  if checkUint8Image
      im = uint8(img);
      [row, column, dim] = size(im);
      im2 = ones(row, column).*255; % white image
      for i=1:row
        for j=1:column
            if(im(i,j) <= par_1)
                im2(i,j) = im(i,j);
            end
        end
     end
     imshow(uint8(im2));
  else
    disp('im paramter is not a uint8 type');
  end
```

Here im2 is casted into uint8.
And also note the line,

```
im2 = ones(row, column).*255;
```